# Some menus not showing in Menu Settings drop down when editing page

Tags: routes

I'm working on a website in Drupal 7.

I have the following menus in admin/structure/menus:

- **About Us Menu** (added)
- Get Connected Menu (added)
- **Main Menu** (default)
- Management (default)
- Navigation (default)
- User Menu (default)

Behind each menu in the list above, I have included "default" if it was included in the Drupal install, or "added" if I have added the menu myself.

I can add any page to any of these menus by using structure/menu/manage/*[MENU NAME]*/add, but I would like for my client to be able to select the menu from when adding or editing a page.

By default, I was able to add pages to the the Main Menu menu from the Menu Settings when adding or editing a page, and after adding the About Us Menu, I was able to add pages to same from this dropdown. However, I added another menu - Get Connected Menu, but I do not see it in the dropdown.

Adding additional test menus, I am still able to see only those that are in bold above - About Us Menu and Main Menu.

Has anyone ever seen this or know of a reason why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Go to *admin/structure/types/* and click the *edit* link next to your content type. In the *Menu settings* tab select the menus you want to be available in the content creation page.

Comment: I never did that for the About Us Menu ... weird.